# Another way to say "これはだれの___ですか？"

Tags: grammar

(the blank represents some noun/object)

Is `この＿＿はだれのですか？` grammatically correct and have the same meaning as the title?

Comment: Rather than 「だれのですか」, I'd recommend 「だれのものですか」.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatically correct and they have almost the same meaning. For example, you can say both:

> これは[誰]{だれ}の[傘]{かさ}ですか？(Lit. Whose umbrella is this?)
>   この[傘]{かさ}は[誰]{だれ}のですか？(Lit. Whose is this umbrella?)

In casual speech we often say:

> これ、誰の傘？
>   この傘、誰の？

Comment: Or even これは誰のですか？ / これ、誰の？ for "Whose is this?" when it's obvious what you're referreing to