# How to ask to whom an item belongs to

Tags: grammar, word-order

The given answer to the question I'm supposed to ask in my workbook is:

> それは　たけしさんの　ぼうし　です。

But I can't figure out if my question should be:

> このぼうしは　だれの　ですか。

OR

> だれの　このぼうし　ですか。

Thank you!

Comment: Which do you think it is?  and why ?

Comment: This thread might be of some help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33157/another-way-to-say-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AE-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/33158

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure out if my question should be このぼうしは　だれの　ですか。OR だれの　このぼうし　ですか。

The first one is correct, because...

---

The genitive case particle の works like the English *'s* or *of*, as in:

> わたしのぼうし my hat
>   あなたのぼうし your hat
>   たけしさんのぼうし Takeshi-san's hat
>   だれのぼうし whose hat
>   わたしのこのぼうし this hat of mine (*lit.* my this hat)

の can also be used for *(someone)'s (stuff)*, as in:

> わたしの mine
>   あなたの yours
>   たけしさんの Takeshi-san's (stuff)
>   だれの whose (stuff)

So...

---

> それはたけしさんのぼうしです。 That is Takeshi-san's hat.

To turn this into a question asking だれの(whose), you'd replace たけしさん with だれ, add the interrogative particle か at the end (and replace それ with これ), as in:

> これは**だれ**のぼうしです**か**。 Whose hat is this?

---

> そのぼうしはたけしさんのです。 That hat is Takeshi-san's.

To turn this into a question, you'd do the same: たけしさん→だれ, です→ですか (and replace その with この this time):

> このぼうしは**だれ**のです**か**。 Whose is this hat?

Answer (score 0):

これは　**だれ**の　ぼうし　ですか。
Whose hat is this?

それは　**たけしさん**の　ぼうし　です。
That is Mr. Takeshi's hat.