# Can you slightly switch up the word order of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, syntax, word-order

This is what I've been taught:

```
       これ は  わたし  の   本   です。
                =  This is my book.
```

And I was just wondering whether you can change the word order to say:

```
       この  本  は   わたし  の  です。
                =  This book is mine.
```

Or if this sentence structure doesn't work.

Comment: both are perfectly fine.

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33157/9831